# Best way to implement menu for ListView items

Tags: android, facebook, listview, menu

I am developing a mobile app that has a functionality similar to Facebook posts feed. For each "post" in my app, I'd like to make available a menu with 3 items (such as like, comment, and share).

As per most part of web results, the most popular approach is to set a ContextMenu and use its API to alter the list content according to menu actions. But the floating menu hides important functionality (and does not allow icons), so I'd rather take Facebook's approach of displaying the items below each post.

Is there any Android API to achieve a similar result? Am I missing some point in this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Internally facebook uses their litho sdk as [here](https://fblitho.com/docs/getting-started)